# Facebook 4.2 iOS 8 logon and post photo

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I’ve got an iPad IOS 8 app using Facebook 4.2 SDK which simply uploads and posts an image and caption to my timeline using graph api.

It used to work fine with Facebook 3.x but it’s broken when I replaced the api.

under 3.x, I ask for permissions using

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"publish_actions",
                        nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error)];
```

and I get switched to FB asking me to allow the app to post.  Also the app appears under the iPad settings for Facebook “Allow these apps to use your account”.

I can then upload/post a photo using
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              fbTextView.text, @"message",
              anImageView.image, @"image",
              nil];

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
 parameters:params
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error)
```

And that’s been working fine.

When I try to do the same using 4.2, first login using

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)];
```

result.declinedPermissions returns null so I assume it’s ok although I did get a screen which said “This does not let the app post to Facebook.”

and then I tried to post the image using

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          fbTextView.text, @"message",
          anImageView.image, @"image",
          nil];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
  initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
  parameters: params
  HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@“no errors”]);

     }
 }];
```

the error prints

> 2015-06-07 14:26:33.472 epiNote HD+[2713:1462469] error:Error
>   Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x17e52320
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=200,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 200;
>               message = "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 403; }, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=403,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#200) Requires
>   extended permission: publish_actions,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}

I’m simply posting to my own timeline and did not need ‘extended permissions’ before.  Has something changed and do I need to re-submit my app for review?

Also the app does not appear in the iPad Settings for Facebook “Allow these apps to use your account”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get your app reviewed again.

Recently, all the permissions except 3 basic ones (email, public)profile and user_friends) have been removed from the app if you had it reviewed by an older version of the Graph API.

Follow the steps as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah thanks!  I discovered that when I added a tester role.  What a pain, didn't need to have review in the past for just a photo upload to my own timeline.

Comment: Cool :) I just solved my issue yesterday, so I thought it may help others

Comment: Actually, I discovered that if you use FBSDKShareKit, you can post photos to your timeline without having to submit the app for review.  But the iOS device needs to have the Facebook app installed.  Works for me.

Comment: I think its right answer, some read permissions are also not appearing in facbook login dialog, and also not asking for publish_actions in dialog after sdk change/upgrade, We need to resubmit or review it again.